# Docker: Unable to access Minio Web Browser

Tags: docker, minio

I am having trouble accessing the Minio embedded web based object browser. The `http://127.0.0.1:9000` and `http://127.0.0.1:45423` addresses immediately shows a "This page isn't working. `ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`".

The `http://172.22.0.8:9000` and `http://172.22.0.8:45423` addresses will load until timeout and land on a "This page isn't working. `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` "

Am I missing something from my Docker setups?

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    minio-image:
        container_name: minio-image
        build:
            context: ./dockerfiles/dockerfile_minio
        restart: always
        working_dir: "/minio-image/storage"
        volumes:
            - ./Storage/minio/storage:/minio-image/storage
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        environment:
            MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio-image
            MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minio-image-pass
        command: server /minio-image/storage
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM minio/minio:latest

CMD wget https://dl.min.io/client/mc/release/linux-amd64/mc && \
    chmod +x mc
```

From minio-image container logs:

```
API: http://172.22.0.8:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000 


Console: http://172.22.0.8:45423 http://127.0.0.1:45423 


Documentation: https://docs.min.io


WARNING: Console endpoint is listening on a dynamic port (45423), please use --console-address ":PORT" to choose a static port.
```

Logging into the docker container through cli and running `pwd` and `ls` results in: `minio-image/storage` and `airflow-files  mlflow-models  model-support-files`, respectively.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see a few problems here.

First, you're only publishing port 9000, which is the S3 API port. If I run your `docker-compose.yml`, access to port 9000 works just fine; on the Docker host, I can run `curl http://localhost:9000` and get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied.</Message><Resource>/</Resource><RequestId>16A25441E50432A4</RequestId><HostId>b1eed50d-9218-488a-9df6-fe008e758b27</HostId></Error>
```

...which is expected, because I haven't provided any credentials.

If you want to access the console, you need to do two things:

- As instructed by the log message, you need to set a static console port using `--console-address`.
- You need to publish this port in the `ports` section of your `docker-compose.yml`.

That gives us:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    minio-image:
        container_name: minio-image
        build:
            context: ./dockerfiles/dockerfile_minio
        restart: always
        working_dir: "/minio-image/storage"
        volumes:
            - ./Storage/minio/storage:/minio-image/storage
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
            - "9001:9001"
        environment:
            MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio-image
            MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minio-image-pass
        command: server /minio-image/storage --console-address :9001
```

Running the above `docker-compose.yml`, I can access the MinIO console
at `http://localhost:9001`, and log in using the
`minio-image`/`minio-image-pass` credentials.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Solid explanation also. Follow up question. This would mean that the api access to access files and such is still on port 9000 correct?